# RestRequest Parameters adding logic

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am having some issues finding information about adding some logic field in my RestRequest using V 107. I am trying to add a filter to my GET query

```
dl_document_indexed_date gt '2020-12-07T08:30:42.483Z'
```

There are a few other queries in the call which i am using Dictionary<string, string> to store them, and it works great however it only works if i am looking for something equal to, as adding it to the parameters it seems by default its equal to and i am not finding any way to add any other logic, gt/ge/lt/le etc. using the older version i would just append the url adding the logic i need, but i am not seeing a way to append the url either. Looking over their documentation i either missed it, cant find it, or its not there. Any help would be greatly appreciated! My method looks like this

```
    public static async Task<string> GET_API(String RequestUrl, string RequestObject, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
            var request = new RestRequest(RequestObject);
            var options = new RestClientOptions(RequestUrl)
            {
                ThrowOnAnyError = true,
                Timeout = -1
            };
            var client = new RestClient(options);
            client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator("Bearer " + TokenManager.GetAccessTokenString("TRN"));

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                request.AddQueryParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
            }

            var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
            return response.Content.ToString();
    }
```

I send the BaseURL , the RequestObject would be table i am calling in the base URL, and my dictionary item contains the Field name, and the field values that i am dynamically generating on another method that would append the string. and example would be

```
 parameters.Add("dl_document_name", "TableA");
```

which would append the URL with dl_document_name eq 'TableA'
it would call the API after i add the OAuth Token i create and return the data i need and send it back. or another option i guess could be appending the string with the logic i need to return the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a work around, if i only have one i can add it to the first parameter and adding the filter as the first key, which will work unless i have multiple conditions that are not eq

```
  parameters.Add("filter","dl_document_indexed_date gt '2020-12-07T08:30:42.483Z'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use OData, it's easy to implement and it has different kind of filters, you also can set which filters are usable and which aren't.

https://www.odata.org/

Comment: can you use Odata with any API client?

Comment: Sure! Every filter has to be written as a Query string on the request uri, and it's processed automatically.
See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/concepts/queryoptions-overview

Comment: You can also take a look to Microsoft Graph Explorer where you can test their API using Odata